# Where does the name `Psycopg` come from?

Tags: python, postgresql

Psycopg is the most popular PostgreSQL adapter for the Python programming language.

The name `Psycopg` does not make sense to me.

I understand the last `pg` means `Postgres`, but what about `Psyco`?

Comment: I can't provide a definitive answer but as some others have pointed out, Psyco might refer to the [Psyco JIT compiler](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psyco)

Answer (score 11):

I've always thought of it as psycho-Postgres.